# How to order records by result of grouped hash in 'belongs_to' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I would like to map records and order them by the results of a hash that counts the number of records in another model that has a 'belongs_to' association with the first.

**tag_follow.rb**

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :user
```

I have a model **tag.rb** with the following methods

```
def self.follow_counts(user)
  counts = TagFollow.group(:tag_id).count

  Tag.order(:tag).map{|t|
    t.followed_count = counts[t.id].to_i
    t
  }
end

def followed_count
  @followed_count ||= TagFollow.where(:tag_id => self.id).count
end
```

Instead of ordering the tag array by the column `:tag` as it currently is, I would like it to be ordered by the count that is the value in the hash of the returned `counts` variable, matching the key with `:tag_id`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a named scope in your Tag model like this:

```
scope :popular, -> { 
  joins(:tag_follows)
  .group("tags.id")
  .order("COUNT(*) DESC")       
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Tag.popular.all
```

to get all of the Tags (that have at least 1 associated `tag_follows` record) in the order of how many `tag_follows` records they are referenced in.

If you want your collection to include Tags that have 0 associated `tag_follows` records, so that every Tag will be in the collection, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
scope :popular, -> { 
  joins("LEFT JOIN tag_follows ON tag_follows.tag_id = tags.id")
  .group("tags.id")
  .order("COUNT(tag_follows.tag_id) DESC")      
}
```

Notice that I changed the `order` parameter so that Tags with 0 `tag_follows` records will be ranked after Tags with 1 `tag_follows` record.

Comment: That did it! +1 for adding the explanation for including tags with 0 associated records, that was exactly what I needed.